# how to remove one property of an object when it is null while adding in table storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

We have below entity inherited from tableEntity

```
public class LinkEntity : TableEntity
{
 public string LinkKey {get; set;}
 public string LinkName {get; set;}
 public int LinkValue {get; set;}
 public string LinkId {get {return PartitionKey;} set;}

 public LinkEntity(Link link)
 {
   PartitionKey = link.LinkId;
   RowKey = link.LinkKey;
   LinkValue =  link.Value;
   LinkName = link.LinkName;
 }
}
```

I have an API that adds the above entity using Post and below steps:

linkValue of Link is null.

```
var cloudTable = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(LinkTable);

cloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var postOperation = TableOperation.Insert(LinkEntity(link));

cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(postOperation);
```

But, when I do get on above, I again receive linkValue as null.
Hence, I don't want to add this value in tableStorage or column/property for entity when this value is null.

I cannot get rid of property linkValue completely because it is being used by other API which is a required field over there. Hence, any advise would be appreciated.

I think there should be some way where we can add required fields and ignore or remove columns completely from entities since tables in table storage is schemaless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR;

Please make the `LinkValue` property nullable. That should solve the problem. So your entity definition would be:

```
public class LinkEntity : TableEntity
{
 public string LinkKey {get; set;}
 public string LinkName {get; set;}
 public int? LinkValue {get; set;}
 public string LinkId {get {return PartitionKey;} set;}

 public LinkEntity(Link link)
 {
   PartitionKey = link.LinkId;
   RowKey = link.LinkKey;
   LinkValue =  link.Value;
   LinkName = link.LinkName;
 }
}
```

Longer Version (Somewhat) :)

As you rightly mentioned, Azure Tables are schema less. Another important thing to understand is that there's no concept of `null` values in an entity in Azure Tables. Either an attribute is present in an entity or it is not.

By keeping `int` as the data type (which has a default value of `0`) for your `LinkValue` attribute, even if you don't provide any value, this attribute will be initialized with default value and that gets stored.

By making the data type as `nullable int`, if you don't provide any value for this attribute, it won't get initialized and will be ignored by the SDK when the entity gets serialized.

However you will need to ensure that the application which consumes this entity (i.e. the receiving end) does not assume that the value will always be present in this attribute and should be prepared to handle null values.

Comment: Thank you. One more question with one tweak, if suppose LinkValue is a string which we encrypt using keyvault and store encrypted value in tableStorage. In that case, keyvault encrypted algorithm throws error if value is null. Hence we make it ''/empty when it is nulll before encrypting the value by algorithm. In that case, we do a get, we receive an empty value for LinkValue. What can be done here?

Comment: I believe this is something you would need to handle in the code. Without knowing more it would be hard to comment.